# How to Group By using Month from date stored as millisecond Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a parking_session table which contains start_time field and end_time field, where both fields are stored as milliseconds. I need to get the total number of parking sessions grouped by using month, year, or date. How can I do this in Laravel?

My table looks like as below:

[image]

and expecting result as:

```
+----------+---------------+
| month    | park_sessions |
+----------+---------------+
| January  | 13
+----------+---------------+
| February | 23            |
+----------+---------------+
| ---      | ----          |
+----------+---------------+
```

What i have tried is

```
 $sessions_all = DB::table('parking_sessions')
    ->pluck('start_time');
    $d = null;
    foreach($sessions_all as $key){
        $d[] = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestampMs($key)->format('Y-M-d');
    }
    
    dd(array_count_values($d));
```

And i get
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in MySQL probably:

```
$result = DB::table('parking_sessions')
             ->selectRaw('MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(start_time * 0.001)) as month, COUNT(*) as park_sessions')
             ->groupBy('month')
             ->get();

dd($result);
```

To include the year in the grouping (or to group by any date format) you can use [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
$result = DB::table('parking_sessions')
             //notice the change to double quotes
             ->selectRaw("DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(start_time * 0.001), '%M-%Y') as month, COUNT(*) as park_sessions") 
             ->groupBy('month')
             ->get();

dd($result);
```

Comment: And how can i group based on current year because now its group all moth's example there is 6 data for  june-2019 and  2 data for june-2020 and its group both as 8 for june. How can i group based on current year. Thanks

Comment: Okay and i have added  YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(start_time * 0.001)) as year and on groupBy i have passed both moth and year and now works